# How to simplify coefficient of Maclaurin series

Tags: calculus, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I have the following exponential generating function G(x),

> \begin{align*}
> {G(x)}&=\left(e^x-1\right)(e^x-1-x)e^x\\
> &{=e^{3x}\color{blue}{-(x+2)e^{2x}+(x+1)e^x}}
> \end{align*}

As far as I see, I can write $e^{3x}$ as $3^n$ although *I don't know the logic behind it.*. But I don't know how to write the blue part as such.

How is the following obtained, for example, $n2^{n-1}$ and the others? Could you please help and explain?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 3^{n} \frac{x^n}{n!} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n2^{n-1} \frac{x^n}{n!} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{n+1} \frac{x^n}{n!} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n+1) \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Comment: $3^n$ can be written as $e^{n\ln(3)}$

Comment: Split the blue part as $-xe^{2x}-2e^{2x}+xe^x+e^x.$ For each summand it is easy to read off the coefficients.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc how to go further for example for $-xe^{2x}$ ? I mean we write $3^n$ for $e^{3x}$. What for $-xe^{2x}$ ?

Comment: $$xe^{2x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {2^n(n+1)x^{n+1}\over (n+1)!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {2^{n-1}nx^{n}\over n!}$$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc You know how to write it but I don't. How do you write it?

Comment: We have $$xe^{2x}=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n{x^n\over n!}$$ The single term is  equal $$2^n{x^{n+1}\over n!}=2^n(n+1){x^{n+1}\over (n+1)!}$$ Then go back to my previous comment. The last step is just a renumeration of the terms in the sum in order to bring to the form $\sum b_n{x^n\over n!}$

Answer (score 2):

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series.

> We obtain for $n\geq 1$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^n]G(x)}&=[x^n]\left(e^{3x}-(x+2)e^{2x}+(x+1)e^x\right)\\
> &=[x^n]e^{3x}-[x^n](x+2)e^{2x}+[x^n](x+1)e^x\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^n]e^{3x}-\left([x^{n-1}]+2[x^n]\right)e^{2x}+\left([x^{n-1}]+[x^n]\right)e^x\tag{2}\\
> &=[x^n]\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(3x)^k}{k!}-\left([x^{n-1}]+2[x^n]\right)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2x)^k}{k!}\\
> &\qquad+\left([x^{n-1}]+[x^n]\right)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{3^n}{n!}-\left(\frac{2^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+2\frac{2^n}{n!}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\frac{1}{n!}\right)\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{n!}\left(3^n-n2^{n-1}-2^{n+1}+n+1\right)}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *linearity* of the *coefficient of* operator.
- In (2) we apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$.
- In (3) we use the series expansion of the series at $x=0$.
- In (4) we select the coefficient of $[x^n]$ and $[x^{n-1}]$.

> Since the constant part of the series is
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^0]G(x)}&=[x^n]\left(e^{3x}-(x+2)e^{2x}+(x+1)e^x\right)\\
> &=1-(0+2)+(0+1)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=0}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
> we obtain from (5) and (6)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{G(x)}&\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(3^n-n2^{n-1}-2^{n+1}+n+1\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}}
> \end{align*}
> according to the claim.